# Use Google 3D-buildings in Matlab's simulation

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-maps, google-earth

I am developing a MATLAB UAV toolbox simulation, and I would like to add realistic characteristics to it.

Is it possible to integrate a 3D view of buildings (Google Maps, Google Earth, or Google Earth Engine) into my simulation?

Example: Use Google Earth 3D-buildings' view and put a drone hovering over it. (including Google Earth Engine)